# psql command doesn't start the latest PostgreSQL installed

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu and just installed Postgres 9.4 from official website using .run package (including pgAdmin and everything)

However I realized that when I type psql in bash it started Postgres 9.2 (may be the built-in version in ubuntu?)

When I run  "/opt/PostgreSQL/bin/psql" it will start 9.4 properly which is the directory I installed 9.4, how should I set it as the default psql?

How can I let bash start the latest 9.4 version when I type psql?

New to Postgres and Ubuntu, plz give a hand, appreciated!

Comment: I am guessing that that isn't the actual error which appears in your terminal. Pasting the actual error into your question might be helpful.

Comment: I'd say they did, but are having issues with text encodings.

Comment: This is not a Postgres problem. You apparently did not remove the old Postgres version and your search path in Ubuntu still contains the bin directory of the old version. Remove the old version or change the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can I have some guide on how to uninstall the old version?